# Raspberry Pi suddenly reboots while idle

Tags: raspbian, boot

I am using the Raspberry Pi with the official touch screen. The power supply is rated 5V 2A. I am going to use it as a data logger and it should not reboot suddenly, but this is what happened after about 45 min in IDLE.

Linux:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #827 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 8 20:29:06 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

How can I trace the reason? Are there any keywords to look for in the log files? E.g. `sudo cat /var/log/messages/syslog | grep boot`

Here is the output of `/var/log/messages` before the reboot:

```
Jan 14 10:17:06 raspberrypi kernel: [    9.671780] wlan0: associated
Jan 14 10:17:06 raspberrypi kernel: [    9.671969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Jan 14 10:17:10 raspberrypi org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor[713]: Volume monitor alive

Jan 14 11:15:34 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Thu Jan 14 11:16:04 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 14 11:17:01 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Thu Jan 14 11:17:31 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 14 11:37:32 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Thu Jan 14 11:38:02 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 14 11:17:04 raspberrypi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="469" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Edit:

It was the cable. I accidentally switched the cable (they look almost the same). I cut both cables and the wrong one had much thinner wires. As a result, only about 600 mA came through.

Comment: Have you looked for the words "fatal", "error", "fault", and other synonyms?

Comment: Have you tested the actual voltage at the board, what the label says is irrelevant, what it actually provides to the Pi is not. Is this the first time this happens? Is it the first time since adding the touchscreen? What else is connected to the Pi? How are these devices connected to the Pi and how are they powered.

Comment: Thanks PandaLion. I will test that.  Steve: True: could be the cable that does limit the power supply. I will test that. I never left it in IDLE for long. Bought it last week. I do not know if this happened before. It is possible. Sometimes the ssh connection was closed. Probably because it rebooted.

Comment: Are you sure your power supply really outputs 5V 2A? I've had a shoddy adapter marked 2A which actually puts out 700mA. How long is your cable, by the way?

Comment: Hm, the adapter is said to provide 2A. But maybe I switched the cable accidentially.

Comment: As usual. I had lots of similar issues until I replaced my power adapter by a cheaper one of better quality than the one I had.